# Install rpy2 inside virtualenv (can't find library)

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have a Python virtualenv set up with [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv). I installed the [R statistical software](https://www.r-project.org/), and now I need to install the [rpy2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io) package to allow communication between Python and R.

Both Python v2.7.12 and R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) are installed.

Attempting to install `rpy2` with `pip install rpy2` fails with:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -llzma
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/gabriel/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/envs/test-env/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-b7O2v3/rpy2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4SXyxe-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/gabriel/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/envs/asteca-env/include/site/python2.7/rpy2" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-b7O2v3/rpy2/
```

`no se puede encontrar -llzma` means `can't find -llzma`.

`python-dev` is already installed in my system.

How can I bypass this issue?

Comment: rpy2 should be working in a virtualenv. Earlier messages printed to the terminal while installing might contain useful information, if you are able to share them.

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to answer @lgautier, I didn't have access to the system where the virtualenv was installed until now. The issue was that I had installed `python-dev` **after** the virtualenv was created. I'll add an answer detailing this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could install the package successfully.

The issue was that I had installed the `python-dev` library *after* the `virtualenv` was created. This caused the installation of the `rpy2` package to fail.

The solution was to uninstall the `virtualenv` and create again from scratch.